# Помощь с базами данных

Tags: c#, база-данных

При создании локальной базы данных в Visual Studio происходит ошибка при загрузке конструктора таблиц. Пишет: Ошибка при загрузке. Конструктор обнаружил ошибку при загрузке определения таблицы.
Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: приведите полный стек ошибки.

Comment: Создаю проект WinForms. Проект - Добавить новый элемент - бд, осн. на службах - имя БД - Добавить. В окне Источники данных - добавить новые источники данных. В окне Мастер настройки источников данных нажать Далее 4 раза (по ум.)-готово. Вид - Обозреватель серверов - Св-ва(разв. узел Подключение данных) - конт. меню ф-ла. mdf - свойства. Обозреватель серверов - разв. Подключение данных - узел mdf. Таблица - Добавить нов. таблицу - откр. Конструктор таблиц.

Comment: стек ошибки, а не последовательность  действий)